# Regex for email firstname.lastname

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm looking to find email address that only match the pattern `firstName.LastName@xxx.yyy` in `Scala / Spark`

My issue is that `"."` is used in Scale regex for "Matches any single character except newline"

I tried with `\\.` but doesn't match as well

Here is my code:

```
val emailTest = "ja.mes@downstairs.com"
if (emailTest.matches("[A-Za-z]+\\.[A-Za-z]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]"))
  println("ok")
else
  println("nok")
```

Thanks for your help

Matthieu

Comment: Simply, uses `[.]`

Comment: Thanks Lamanus but it doesn't work neither

Answer (score 3):

The `.` is fine, but you are only looking for one character after the `@`. Add a `+` to fix this:

```
"[A-Za-z]+\\.[A-Za-z]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+"
```

Comment: [this site](https://jex.im/regulex/) is a great way to visualise the behaviour of a regular expression.